# price in menu+total price (pascal)

Tags: debugging, freepascal

My program should allow the user to choose ice cream from menu then add the price for the ice cream to show total price of the ice cream.However my output for total price is wrong. For example if i choose 1 and 2 the answer should be 1.5+1.7=3.2 but I get 3.4. Also if i choose 2 I'll only get error. Please help me.

```
program iceCream;

var
  count,i: integer;
  price:array[1..50]of real;
  totalPrice: real;
  choice: integer;

begin
  count:= 0;

  writeln ( ' ICE CREAM FLAVOUR');
  write ( ' 1.Vanilla: RM 1.50 |  3.Chocolate: RM 2.00');
  writeln;
  write ( ' 2. Strawberry: RM 1.70 | 0. Exit ');
  writeln;

  repeat
    write ( ' Enter your choice(number): ');
    readln ( choice);
    if choice <= 3 then
      count:= count+1
    else
      writeln ( 'Invalid choice');

    case choice of

      1: begin
           price[i]:= 1.50;
         end;

      2: begin
           price[i]:= 1.70 ;
         end;

      3: begin
           price[i]:= 2.00;
         end;

    end;

    for i:= 1 to count do
    begin
      totalPrice:= totalPrice+price[i];
    end;

  until choice = 0;

  writeln ( ' Total ice-cream: ', count);
  readln;
  writeln ( ' Total price: RM ', totalPrice:2:2);
  readln;

end.
```

Answer (score 1):

**I won't answer** your question here. It's more important to find out what you're doing wrong and **how you can solve the problem on your own**.

**How to find out what's going wrong?**

The compiler shows two warnings when it compiles your code:

> **Warnings: 2**
>
> **project1.lpr(29,17) Warning:** Variable "i" does not seem to be initialized
>
> **project1.lpr(44,25) Warning:** Variable "totalPrice" does not seem to be initialized

This kind of warnings appears when you read a variable without having a value assigned to it. The compiler leads you to the location of the unsafe code. The first warning is located in line 29 in column 17:

```
1: begin
     price[i]:= 1.50; // i has not been set before. So its value is undefined or 0
   end;
```

Is your intention to use set `Price[i]` here? So why hasn't it been assigned to a value before?
Or do you have a different variable that holds the number of ice creams? Why don't you use that?

Let's take a look at the second warning in line 44 in column 25. It's this line:

```
totalPrice:= totalPrice+price[i];      
//           ^
```

Are you sure `totalPrice` has been initialized correctly?

Even though you initialize it correctly the program may still doesn't work properly. In that case it helps to **debug** the application. 
Open your application in the [Lazarus IDE](http://www.lazarus-ide.org/) and press `F8` to step through your program. You go from line to during the execution of your program. You will see what's wrong then.